# Decode json and foreach Shows key but not value

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach

I cant seem to get the value from the foreach below. I need to basically create a loop where i can then create html buttons based on selections.

I have also added a snippet example only below this text to show what im trying to achieve within the foreach. I just need to work out how to extract the values so i can do that.

I am basically wanting to create a foreach loop that checks how many buttons the user has added and then display each button within the loop with a link in href and a custom button name. I will also have to check of they chose 1,2,3,4 from the showBtn value to determine what type of html to output.

```
if showBtn==1 { <a herf="btnMenuLink">btnName</a> }

if showBtn==3 { <a herf="btnPhone">btnName</a> }
```

I have the following code of which i have provided the outputs of the database content and also a var_dump just so you can see how the information is being stored.

The following code does output the key for me but it wont output the values. And i suspect its because my values are an array as well. How on earth would i create a loop within a loop within a loop and still achieve what i explained above?

```
<?php

$jsonresult =  $column->links;
$array = json_decode($jsonresult,true);

// The databse TEXT field    
/*{
"showBtn":["3","3"],
"btnMenuLink":["101","101"],
"btnArticleLink":["2","2"],
"btnPhone":["036244789","0404256478"],
"btnURL":["",""],
"btnName":["Office","Mobile"]
}*/

// The Var dump $array    
/*  array(6) {
    ["showBtn"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "3" [1] => string(1)
        "3"
    }["btnMenuLink"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(3)
        "101" [1] => string(3)
        "101"
    }["btnArticleLink"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(1)
        "2" [1] => string(1)
        "2"
    }["btnPhone"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(9)
        "036244789" [1] => string(10)
        "0404256478"
    }["btnURL"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(0)
        "" [1] => string(0)
        ""
    }["btnName"] => array(2) {
        [0] => string(6)
        "Office" [1] => string(6)
        "Mobile"
    }
} */

foreach($array as $key => $value) { ?>    
<?php echo $key;?>:<?php echo $value;?><hr/>    
<?php } ?>
```

Im still kind of stuck on this,

please find below what im after:

```
$jsonresult = '{"showBtn":["3","3"],"btnMenuLink":["101","101"],"btnArticleLink":["2","2"],"btnPhone":["036244789","0404256478"],"btnURL":["",""],"btnName":["Office","Mobile"]}';

$array          =   json_decode($jsonresult,true);

foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $next_key => $next_value) { 
        echo $key.":".$next_key.":".$next_value."\n";
    } }

// I want this

// if(showBtn==3) {

// echo '<a herf='tel:btnPhone'>btnName</a>';

// }

// the result would be

// <a href="tel:036244789">Office</a> <a href="tel:0404256478">Mobile</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be because your `$value` is an array, not a set value. You'll need to loop it one more time:

```
foreach($array as $key => $values) {
    foreach($values as $item) {
         echo $key . ":" . $item;
    }
    echo "<hr />";
}
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/328666)

Comment: you are classic! Thanks mate ;)

Comment: @JohnRama Pleasure mate, it's always the small ones that we miss :P

Comment: how do i extract the  keys so i can do some if statements? Example $item->btnName

Comment: Which keys do you mean @JohnRama? like `showBtn` or the other ones like `3`,`101`...etc ?

Comment: Oh right! Change `foreach($values as $item)` to `foreach($values as $check_key => $item)` and then you can do your `if showBtn = $check_key {....`

Comment: sorry last question i promise. Im trying to determine what showBtn will look like. if( $check_key['showBtn']==3){...

Comment: @JohnRama Can you clarify what you mean by that? What do you want it to look like?

Comment: if ($key['showBtn']=='1'){ echo '<a class="btn btn-primary' herf='$key['btnLink']'>$key['btnName']</a>}. That would return that one menu link was added. Then in the same loop there might be another button with a phone number link etc...

Comment: I have come back to this in the hope you be able to help. I made sample in the same place you did on the eval.in site. https://eval.in/private/e56066d4dbec47

Comment: I just can not seem to see how i can associate the key with the respective value within an if statement

Comment: @JohnRama I'll sort this out for you soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        echo "this is a nested loop";
    }
}
```

So `$value2` will contain the elements in the array.

Also, if you are not seeing any error or warning messages when you do `echo $value;` you should turn on `error_reporting` as it is extremely useful when developing.

Comment: thanks for this but i had to give it to Darren as he basically posted first and it does do what i want. I have to make further adjustments form here anyways.

Comment: i am still stuck on this mate. I have added more code to my post and also a link to show what im after. https://eval.in/private/e56066d4dbec47 If you could help i would much appreciate